# Not exists not working as per expectation in Amazon Redshift database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to do a `not exists` for the below scenario, But I am getting the error message

> This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

**Table1**

| pkey | name | dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | TONY | SALES |
| 456 | JACK | HR |
| 789 | CHRIS | IT |

**Table2**

| ipkey | pkey | src |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 123 | A |
| 222 | 123 | B |
| 333 | 456 | A |
| 444 | 789 | A |
| 555 | 789 | C |

My requirement is not to fetch the src `C` data, and fetch other details from `table1` and `table2`.

Sql tried:

```sql
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on (t1.pkey = t2.pkey)
where t1.src in ('A','B')
and not exists 
( 
select 1 from table2 t2i 
where t1.pkey = t2i.pkey
and t2i.src = 'C'
)
```

Expecting result set:

| pkey | name | dept | ipkey | src |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | TONY | SALES | 111 | A |
| 123 | TONY | SALES | 222 | B |
| 456 | JACK | HR | 333 | A |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not need to use the `Not Exixts` keyword for your use case.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName1 
(
    pkey    INT,
    name    VARCHAR(512),
    dept    VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO tableName1 (pkey, name, dept) VALUES ('123', 'TONY', 'SALES');
INSERT INTO tableName1 (pkey, name, dept) VALUES ('456', 'JACK', 'HR');
INSERT INTO tableName1 (pkey, name, dept) VALUES ('789', 'CHRIS', 'IT');


CREATE TABLE tableName2 
(
    ipkey   INT,
    pkey    INT,
    src VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO tableName2 (ipkey, pkey, src) VALUES ('111', '123', 'A');
INSERT INTO tableName2 (ipkey, pkey, src) VALUES ('222', '123', 'B');
INSERT INTO tableName2 (ipkey, pkey, src) VALUES ('333', '456', 'A');
INSERT INTO tableName2 (ipkey, pkey, src) VALUES ('444', '789', 'A');
INSERT INTO tableName2 (ipkey, pkey, src) VALUES ('555', '789', 'C');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName1 T1
INNER JOIN tableName2 T2 ON T2.pkey = T1.pkey
AND T2.pkey NOT IN (SELECT pkey FROM tableName2 WHERE src IN ('C'));
```

| pkey | name | dept | ipkey | pkey | src |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | TONY | SALES | 111 | 123 | A |
| 123 | TONY | SALES | 222 | 123 | B |
| 456 | JACK | HR | 333 | 456 | A |

---

Comment: Thank you and Agree to the SQL . It Holds good.